# How to call my program if core dump happens?

Tags: linux, coredump

I have configured the core_pattern like this:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/var/core_interceptor/bin/core_handler_program.sh
```

If I generate the core by killing the process by `kill -4 <PID>`:

```
$ cat crash.sh 
#!/bin/sh

while true
do
   echo "PID is $$"
   sleep 100000
done

$ ./crash.sh 
PID is 92658
Illegal instruction (core dumped)

$ cat core_handler_program.sh 
echo "this program will handle core dump"
#!/bin/bash
#touch "/var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.happened.$(date +%T)"
touch "/var/core_interceptor/bin/core.happened.$(date +%T)"
```

My program is not getting called because I don't see `core.happened` file in `/var/core_interceptor/bin` dir.

```
ls -lrt core*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 176 Sep  7 19:38 core_handler_program.sh
```

Any idea why my program is not getting called?

**EDIT**: I created a `c program` and configured in `core_pattern` and this binary is getting called. It generates the `text.text` file successfully.

```
$ cat hello.c
#include <stdio.h>
#define FILE_NAME "/var/core_interceptor/bin/text.txt"
int main()
{
   // printf() displays the string inside quotation
   printf("Hello, World!");
   FILE* file_ptr = fopen(FILE_NAME, "w");
   fclose(file_ptr);
   return 0;
}
```

Is there any limitation that only binaries can be configured? Or is it possible to invoke `shell script` also?

Comment: Your core_handler_program.sh must at least begin with the `#!/bin/bash` part, you can't start it with an echo statement.

Comment: Yes that was the issue :( I wasted a day and half :(
Thanks a lot!!!